# Microsoft Teams Adaptive Card not rendering on iOS

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

New to adaptive cards - this renders fine on desktop when sent via a webhook but just shows up blank on iOS. Am I missing something obvious? Thank you

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "size": "extraLarge",
                        "weight": "bolder",
                        "text": "Test"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "FactSet",
                        "facts": [
                            {
                                "title": "Test 1",
                                "value": "Test 1"
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "Test 2",
                                "value": "Test 2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "version": "1.4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: We also tried with the JSON provided and observed that though the card gets rendered properly in Teams desktop/web client, it doesn't render in iOS. We also tried upgrading/degrading the card version, still same result.

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!

Comment: Currently there is no update to share. We are following up with engineering team on the same. We will inform you once we have any update. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"`$schema`", "`version`" and "`type`" need to be at the same level of the JSON.

See this: https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/

JSON should look like this:

```
{
   "type":"AdaptiveCard",
   "body":[
      {
         "type":"TextBlock",
         "size":"extraLarge",
         "weight":"bolder",
         "text":"Test"
      },
      {
         "type":"FactSet",
         "facts":[
            {
               "title":"Test 1",
               "value":"Test 1"
            },
            {
               "title":"Test 2",
               "value":"Test 2"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
   "version":"1.4"
}
```

This works fine in all the clients (Desktop/Web/Android/iOS):

iOS:

[image]